# Is it possible to use `~` or environment variables in the gitdir option for git repositories?

Tags: git, version-control

I want to be able to use environment variables for path expansion in my git settings.

I have a git repo set up with a separate git directory:

```bash
git init --separate-git-dir $HOME/bare_repos/.mygitdir
```

This creates a git repository, with a `.git` file containing the `gitdir` field. However the path in the field is fully expanded,

```
> cat .git
gitdir: C:/Users/MYNAME/bare_repos/.mygitdir
#       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
#      I want this to remain $HOME for portability
```

Is there a way to have a variable (`~` or `$HOME` etc) in the `.git` file? For example, changing the `.git` file to this gives an error:

```
gitdir: $HOME/bare_repos/.mygitdir

> git status

# fatal: not a git repository: CURRENT/PATH/$HOME/bare_repos/.mygitdir
```

*Note:* I understand I can pre-set the `GIT_DIR` environment variable before calling git commands (`GIT_DIR="$HOME/bare_repos/.mygitdir";git status`). But I want to be able to skip that manual variable setting in each terminal session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is substitution in a .git file created by a [`git init --separate-git-dir=<git-dir>`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-init#Documentation/git-init.txt---separate-git-dirltgit-dirgt)   command.

No amount of `~`, `%VAR%` or `${VAR}` would work.
Git always precede those by `CURRENT/PATH`

The best I came up with was using a *relative* path:

```bash
cat .git
gitdir: ../path/to/.mygitdir
```